# Python/Travis-Ci exception "from request urllib.request.urlretrieve ImportError: No module named"

Tags: python, travis-ci, urllib, urlretrieve

I'm trying to run python script throw Travis-CI

I import:

```
from urllib.request import urlretrieve

 urlretrieve(download_url, save_local)
```

when I run this script in my local machine I have no problem, but when I call the script file throw travis.yml I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./scripts/python/file.py", line 6, in <module>
from urllib.request import urlretrieve
ImportError: No module named request
```

I create "requirements.txt", but it didn't work as expected

What am I missing?

Comment: What version is the Travis-CI for Python?

Comment: It's the SaaS version of Travis-CI,

Comment: For me, `from urllib.request import urlretrieve` works on `python3`, but not on `python2`. Are you using a python3 for your tests?